# The value is a mix of lists and tuples. How to read them?

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I have the value shown, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uecl04alg60q881/variable.txt?dl=1), returned by a variable in my `Python` script.

As you can see, the value is a combination of lists and tuples. How can we read the value in the file above?

For instance, I have the following indexes for the value shown. How can we locate the value of each index in the main value shown in the file?

```
[[ 64  85]
 [ 65  66]
 [ 67  86]
 [ 68  87]
 [ 70  68]
 [ 71  74]
 [ 72  71]
 [ 73  56]
 [ 74  62]
 [ 75  89]
 [ 76  91]
 [ 77  92]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please move the dropbox content into your question (perhaps a simplified shorter version of the data that can reproduce the issue).

Comment: @wim Thanks for your comment. The content is large, and that's why I attached a file instead.

Answer (score 1):

If all the newlines `\n` in the file are replaced with commas `,`, the content of the file is legal python. Thus the file can be read as

```
import ast

with open('variable.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
data = ast.literal_eval(text.replace('\n', ','))
```

Now `data` is a `list` containing nested `list`s and `tuple`s. Exactly how to make sense of your indices in the question is not obvious, but now at least you can do things like `data[0][1][2]` and get out a number.